# Creating browser extension or other script for my client, using, JS

Tags: javascript

I want to build an browser extension, or some kind of script to give to my client that will provide custom keyboard shortcuts that store commonly used phrases and quickly inserts them. I'm not very familiar with JS but would like to learn just enough to accomplish this particular task. Where would I want to look to create a program that will pre-load text strings and add them to an email, facebook post, etc. with a keyboard shortcut? can I assign function keys to my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mousetrap.js. "A simple library for handling keyboard shortcuts in Javascript."

Also you can get more information how to use that natively
https://medium.com/@melwinalm/crcreating-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascripteating-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript-763ca19beb9e

Comment: okay so I want to create a basic "Hello, just touching base" keyboard shortcut for an email, and I'm not developing a website per se, but an extension or program that will interface with gmail and facebook to automate this string of text, do you have an example for me?

Comment: So for that you can write automation scripts for different purpose. I have came across a nice automation framework which might be easy in your case. http://nightwatchjs.org/

Comment: So I've literally never done any JS work, so I download the mousetrap framework, and nightwatch and start building a browser extension, or can I just run my script in the background? How do do I give my script to someone else?